# I get errors ('module-discoveryDocs.zip' doesn't exist) when setting project module dependencies in google endpoints version 2

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I have errors when setting project module dependencies in google endpoints version 2. I tried endpointsServer project(path: ':module-one', configuration: 'endpoints')

In endpoints version 1.0 you can just do

```
deploy project(path: ':module-one', configuration: 'archives')
```

inside the dependencies.

Trying

```
dependencies {

    endpointsServer project(path: ':module-one', configuration: 'endpoints')
    endpointsServer project(path: ':module-two', configuration: 'endpoints')
    endpointsServer project(path: ':module-three', configuration: 'endpoints')
    compile "com.google.api-client:google-api-client:+"
}
```

Is giving errors when I try gradle build

The error looks like

```
Execution failed for task ':some-project:_extractServerDiscoveryDocs'.
> src 'project-path\prax-one-ui\build\distributions\module-one-discoveryDocs.zip' doesn't exist.
```

I got some explanation on using endpointsServer from here
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/endpoints-framework-gradle-plugin/blob/master/ANDROID_README.md

I will really appreciate any help

Comment: Can you show us the modules and main gradle files so we can have a closer look?

Comment: Did you find a solution?